# Search for string duplicate in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have multidimensional array with strings:

```
const arr = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 'a']]
```

How can i log to console all values that occur in all nested arrays more than 1 time? (For this example function should console.log 'a' and 'd').

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can create a set and add them, check if exists, `console.log` them. I can create a fiddle if you need

Comment: Looks like a dupe question, looking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let findDupesInMDArray = (arr) => {
  // flatten the array
  const flat = arr.flat();
  // filter for dupes
  return flat.filter((item, index) => flat.indexOf(item) != index)
}

let array = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 'a']]
const dupes = findDupesInMDArray(array)
console.log(dupes)
```

Answer (score 4):

You first flat the arr.Then remove duplicates from it using **[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)**. And loop through it then compare `lastIndexOf` and `indexOf`

```js
const arr = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 'a']]
let flat = arr.toString().split(',');
[... new Set(flat)].forEach(a => {
  if(flat.indexOf(a) !== flat.lastIndexOf(a)) console.log(a)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using spread syntax, Array#flat, Array#reduce, Array#filter and Array#map.

```js
const arr = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 'a']]

const res = Array.from(arr.flat().reduce((a,c)=>{
  return a.set(c, (a.get(c)||0) + 1);
}, new Map()))
.filter(([,c])=> c > 1)
.map(([k])=>k);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count the items by using a `Map` and get only the items with a count greater than one.

```js
const 
    count = (m, a) => Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce(count, m) : m.set(a, (m.get(a) || 0) + 1);

var array = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 'a']],
    result = Array
        .from(array.reduce(count, new Map), ([k, v]) => v > 1 && k)
        .filter(Boolean)
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more basic approach:

```
var array = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 'a']]
  var result = [];
  for (var i in array){
   for (var l in array[i]){
    if(array[i][l]==='a'||array[i][l]==='d')
      result.push(array[i][l])
}}

var unique = new Set(result) //creates a set with unique values
console.log(unique) //should log the set {'a','d'}
```

What we're doing here is

1. looping through the nested arrays twice
2. pushing the elements (if the element === 'a' or element ==='d') into a new array called result.
3. creating a new set with the unique values only